# How to make browser use discrete Radeon GPU

Tags: gpu, amd-radeon, amd-catalyst, webgl, discrete-graphics

I recently bought a Samsung Ativ Book 8, which has a AMD Radeon HD 8870M GPU with 2 GB GDDR5.

It has AMD catalyst installed to manage switching between GPU's for different apps/power usages. I put all options AMD Catalyst on high performance, and also set Chrome to run in High performance mode.

Though when I run a simple WebGL demo (like the Chrome Aquarium demo) I get about 20 Fps on medium settings (not very good). I then downloaded GPU-Z and noticed that indeed the CPU load of the Intel HD 4000 was quite high when running this demo, and the Radeon seems inactive.

When I run a game it does show a high GPU Core Clock for the Radeon, so that seems to work just fine. Also Samsung installed a handy update tool, which updated all the drivers recently, so that shouldnt be a problem.

Chromes setting "use hardware acceleration" is on.
A webgl demo in firefox was also using the internal Intel GPU.

When I disable the internal GPU through windows decive manager, windows falls back to the "Microsoft basic display driver" instead of going through the discrete GPU.(not sure if thats normal?)

I installed FurMark (GPU testing app) and when I click on GPU Shark (with both GPU's enabled) I get the following output:

```
Current graphics drivers not supported
Trying to load available information...

- Graphics card: Intel HD Graphics 4000 (M)
- Graphics driver: 9.17.10.2963 (1-16-2013) - GL:atig6pxx.dll
- GPI: IvyBridge(GT2)
- BIOS: Intel Video BIOS
- Unified shader cores: 16
- TPD: 35W
- Memory size: -1984MB
- Device ID: 80860166
- OpenGL renderer: AMD Radeon HD 8800M Series
OpenGL 4.2.11932 Compatibility Profile Context with 238 extionsions
- GLSL 4.20
- OpenCL OpenCL 1.1
```

Any idea how I can run Webgl things over the discrete GPU?

Comment: For chrome look at chrome://gpu/ to see what it sees in regards to GPU(s) and their capabilities.

Comment: tnx, just did, and it shows Intel HD Graphics 4000 all over the place. No further problems "everything OK". But that's not really 'ok' for me ;)