# WebGL unavailable in Chrome; "chrome://gpu" says "GPU process was unable to boot"

Tags: google-chrome, graphics-card, gpu, webgl

When I first installed Chrome on this new laptop, WebGL worked fine on it. Now it doesn't, and I don't know what broke it. Maybe it was the fact that I installed the official AMD/Intel GPU switchable drivers from HP.

`chrome://gpu` says:

> GPU process was unable to boot: Features are disabled upon full but not preliminary GPU info.

Any hints?

**Note**: WebGL works fine in Firefox.

**Note**: There are several questions on this site about WebGL being unavailable in Chrome, but I think none of them has the "GPU process was unable to boot" message.

Comment: Had similar problem, this one helped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40472961/webgl-unavailable-gpu-process-unable-to-boot

Comment: @yarl: Thanks. Enabling "Override software rendering list" helped, but only until heavy shaders in shadertoy.com crashed my webgl a couple of times. Now webgl fully refuses to work in Chrome again, and `chrome://gpu` says "GPU process was unable to boot: GPU access is disabled in chrome://settings.". This is despite the "Use hardware acceleration" checkbox in settings being checked.